# Dynamic binding in Objective C on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was writing an application for iPhone, i have a class A and a class B, each one of them, has a property called IDS, when i defined NSArray of objects of type A, and defined NSArray of objects of type B, then i requested them using that expression,

```
  ids = [[Array objectAtIndex:0] IDS];
```

and it worked on the simulator, but when i run on a real iPhone, the IDE refused that and i was have to cast to be something like that:

```
  ids = [(A*)[Array objectAtIndex:0] IDS];
```

anyone can show me why it runs on simulator and got errors on real device.

Error is:

> multiple methods called IDS found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Comment: mutliple methods called IDS found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Comment: what is IDS method? and what does it return?

Comment: it's a a property NSInteger

Comment: Show the declaration of both class A and class B.

Comment: Just a note: if your classes implement the same methods and you need to call these methods on objects of both (in your case) classes, but you don't want to inherit them from a common ancestor, it's better to declare these methods in a protocol. And then you can treat an array of objects of types A and B as an array of objects that implement a common protocol. It's much more readable, it shows your intentions better, and it gives you and other developers some guarantees.

Comment: This isn't dynamic binding, its duck typing. If the message being sent to the target object is compatible then the target object will handle it. Its not clear why you're getting an error.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely a difference between 32-bit and 64-bit compilation.

```
@interface Foo1 : NSObject
@property int bar;
@end

@interface Foo2 : NSObject
@property NSInteger bar;
@end
```

In 32-bit, both `bar` methods return a 32-bit integer and therefore have the same signature.  In 64-bit, the two `bar` methods have difference signatures; one returns a 32-bit integer, the other returns a 64-bit integer.  When compiling for 64-bit, the compiler needs you to specify which method you mean.

When you compile for the device you're compiling both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your code.  When you compile for the simulator you may only be compiling for 32-bit code, depending on which simulator you're targeting

Comment: interesting. I didn't aware this.

Comment: Seems like the problem solved. Thank for the deep explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I will re-write the line to:

```
NSInteger ids = -1;
if(Array.count > 0) {
  // double confirm it's and A-class object
  if([[Array objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[A class]]) {
    A* obj = (A*)[Array objectAtIndex:0];
    ids = [obj IDS];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Invalid Class: %@", [[Array objectAtIndex:0] class]);
  }
} else {
  NSLog(@"There is nothing in the Array");
}
```

You should always do some checkings; avoid one-liner.

Comment: That's great, but i just wanna know why it worked on simulator without any checking or casting ??!!!

Comment: somehow the data in `Array` is not the same with those in simulator. Caching / data corruption may appear. Clean install the App again and retry.

Comment: Or replace instanceof with polymorphism, as the OP has done. (albeit in an unconventional way. better to conform to a protocol or abstract base. . though I can see the question is for research/understanding purposes).